# Cypress Testing Angular App Login Session Timeouts

Tags: angular, cypress, session-timeout

I'm trying to set up Cypress to test a session timeout in an Angular app, using the Node Package Manager to install modules. Right now the session timeout is set to wait an hour. It would be easy to get a Cypress test to wait an hour, but I've been asked to help find a way to get a test to run faster. The session timeout is set as an hour currently, and is defined in a typescript file, specifically an app.module.ts. The Angular app is setup to use the 'angular-user-idle' module to count idle time before a timeout. This idle time is defined in an imports statement, using the UserIdleModule.forRoot({idle: X, timout: Y}) function, defined in the following structure. I have removed unrelated modules to hopefully make it more readable

```js
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    Component Declarations 
  ],
  imports: [
    Other Modules
    UserIdleModule.forRoot({ idle: 3600, timeout: 5 }) // for session-exipred function, entries are in seconds
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    },
    DatePipe
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Really the summary of the question is, is there anyway to modify the UserIdleModule.forRoot({idle: X, timeout: Y}) function when running a Cypress test?

Not sure it's possible, probably is a bad idea, but I figured I'd get a second opinion before scraping the idea entirely. Sorry if my question is unclear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Cypress provides `cy.clock()` and `cy.tick()` commands to allow timeframes to be compressed for testing.

It works based on controlling native browser `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` functions.

Looking at `UserIdleModule` it uses ReactiveX (rxjs) which at it's core has `setInterval()` to do scheduling, so there's a reasonable chance this will work

```js
cy.clock()
cy.visit('/')

// perform login

cy.tick(3600 * 1000)  // move clock by 1 hour (defined in ms)

// verify logged out
```